# Database design: How to store the days of the month in a table?

Tags: database-design

In a relational database, how do you store the days of the month in a table?
For a project I have to save prices based on the day of the month. For example:

```
Day of month   price
--------------------
Day 1          32
Day 2          50
Day 29         60
Day 30         28
Day 31         49
```

Is a separate column for all days the way to go, albeit slightly redundant? For instance, the month February never has more than 29 days. Multiple entity instances rely on the prices and days.

For the sake of simplicity, I don't prefer to go with two extra tables saving the months and the related days respectively.

Comment: Would day depends on months? like 1st day of Jan, 1st day of Feb

Comment: No, only in the sense that February has 29 days maximum. I will solve that programmatically. I was wondering if there are any other (better) approaches than just simply making 31 columns; the maximum amount of days in a month.

Comment: Creating 31 columns would sure be the wrong way. Why not simply create 31 rows of day number and price if you can handle February programmatically?

Comment: Then you can go how @Filburt mentioned

Comment: I have multiple entity instances that rely on the prices of the month. In that case, prices differ per entity. I'm sorry that was not clear in my question.

A row like you described would contain a day number, a price and an entity_id. Not my preference, since I would get the amount of entities times 31 (max amount of days in a month) in rows.

Then again, if that's the only solution, I guess I have to settle for that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Having a relation to another entity of course changes things a little. The advantage will be if you ever need to handle days in months individually, the required schema change is relatively simple as well as the changes in the programming logic. Unless you have millions of  entity instances any decent RDBMS will be able to handle this fine.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I will implement this solution in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Just want you to bit more clear If you use MySQL

```
 CREATE TABLE `pice_aganist_date` (
      `day` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`day`)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed, but I was unclear in my question. I have multiple entity instances and I would have to add an entity_id to this table in order to make it work for all entities. Anyway, if that's the best approach, I guess I have to settle for that. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @EricLandheer Consider the performance benefit if you are able to optimize indexes for querying prices for all entity instances for a given day.

Comment: @EricLandheer To keep price different for every entity you can add entity_id afterwards make a composite primary key(entity_id, day).

Comment: Thanks @MithuCN, see my answer from half an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this was the solution to my problem. (thanks to Mithu CN and Filburt)

```
CREATE TABLE `entity_prices` (
    `day` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `entity_id` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`day`, `entity_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES Entities(`id`)
);
```

[image: Final result]

Replace entity_id with the name of the column you want to reference.

Answer (score 1):

> In a relational database, how do you store the days of the month in a table?

Usually, you don't. Usually, you store the date, and you extract the day when you need it. One potential problem with this code . . .

```
CREATE TABLE `entity_prices` (
    `day` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `entity_id` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`day`, `entity_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES Entities(`id`)
);
```

. . . is that you can store only one row for each day for each entity. For example, you can store this.

```
day   price  entity_id
--
  1      13         27
  2      14         27
  3      13         27  
...
 25      15         27
```

Having stored the row `{25, 15, 27}` on, say, 2018-09-25, you can't *also* store the row `{25, 15, 27}` on 2018-10-25.

Also, is that first row current data? Is it left over from last year, or 15 years ago? You can't tell by looking at it. That might violate one of the fundamentals of relational theory: all data is represented by rows of columns in tables. If you somehow know that the first row is current, then that data (the knowledge about the age of the first row) comes from *outside* the database.

Also, today is the 25th. You can't insert a row for today for entity_id 27; you'd get a duplicate primary key. Instead, you have to either update the row for the 25th, or delete it before inserting. Both cases *lose* the data for the row `{25, 15, 27}`.

Whether any of this matters is application-dependent, but it matters far more often than not.

If you store the date instead of the day, you can *always* insert one row for entity_id 27 for today. You *always* know whether the row represents data for the current day or month or year. You can always extract the day when you need it. (`extract (day from date <your date column>) where <your date column> between '2018-09-01' and '2018-09-30'`). And there's no substantial performance penalty if you have a dbms that can create indexes on expressions, or if you delete old rows regularly.

The proposed structure in MySQL (copied above) suffers from other problems, too. The column "day", when declared as a signed tinyint, can store values from -128 to 127. Most of those values aren't valid, but valid values are hard to enforce in general in MySQL (MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints), and essentially impossible when you store "day" without also storing its month. Storing a date instead solves these kinds of problems.

The column "price" has similar problems--something called a price should never be negative. But without support for CHECK constraints, the database designer is left looking for workarounds--foreign keys, triggers, etc.